# want to set my navbar links at a width of 100% of their container but by doing so my sprite image becomes width of 100%

Tags: navigation, width, sprite, gradient

I have a fixed horizontal navigation bar at the top of my page. I'm doing responsive design so the width of the navbar is 100% and each individual list item is 25% width of the total nav bar(as there are four).
I have an icon in the middle of each list item of the navbar and i have my hyperlinks set to display block and width as 100% of the list item they are contained in so that you can click anywhere on each nav item and it will go to the desired page.
I would like to put my icons on a sprite so that there are less http requests because at the moment i have them as separate images as you can see from the last 3 list items of my html headernav code below:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="headernav">  
                <li><a id="home" href="#"></a></li>  
                <li><a class="gradient_black" href="locate8.htm#"><img class="headericons" src="images/maps_30_white1.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Find Us" /></a></li>  
                <li><a class="gradient_black" href="#"><img class="headericons" src="images/phone_white.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Click to Call" /></a></li>  
                <li><a class="gradient_black" href="more5.htm#"><img class="headericons" src="images/arrow_white.png" height="30" width="30" alt="More" /></a></li>  
        </ul>  
</div>
```

The first list item above uses the id 'home' which i have defined in my css below. The problem is that as the width of my hyperlink is 100% therefore the sprites width becomes 100% and the full sprite image is shown instead of just (in this case) the house image. How can I layer the sprite on top of the gradient (which i have as background for each link) while keeping the width of the sprite as just e.g 46px but also keep the width of the link as 100% of the link item?  Thanks for any help.
Here is my css

```
#header {
width: 100%;
position:fixed;
 /*height of the header navigation 60 and border 2px*/
overflow-y: hidden;
z-index: 2;
}

#headernav {  
 width: 100%;  
    background: #000;
    font-size: 1.5em;  
position: relative;  
}  
.border{

border-bottom: 2px solid #868783;  

}
#headernav li {  
    display: inline;  
    float: left;  
width: 25%;
 border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    box-sizing:border-box;  
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;  
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;  
border-bottom: 1px solid #868783;  
height: 60px;

} 
#headernav a {  
    color: #fff;  
    display: block;  /*displays the link as a block which stretches to the width specified-100% of its parent*/
    width: 100%;/*width of link is 100% the width of its parent*/
    text-align: center;  /*puts the text of the link in the centre of the display block*/
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
height: 60px;
}  
#home{left: 100px; width:46px; margin: auto;}
#home{
background: url('images/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0 no-repeat, -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a9acad 14%, #050303 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: url('images/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0 no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(14%,#a9acad), color-stop(100%,#050303)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: url('images/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0 no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a9acad 14%,#050303 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: url('images/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0 no-repeat, -o-linear-gradient(top, #a9acad 14%,#050303 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: url('images/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0 no-repeat, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a9acad 14%,#050303 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: url('images/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0 no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, #a9acad 14%,#050303 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a9acad', endColorstr='#050303',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

height: 60px;


}
```

http://m.sarahsfreeringtones.com/images/img_navsprites.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this. I have put a span tag (with id="home") inside the anchor tag and added display:block; to my home id in css. Without the 'display:block' added to the span tag, the image would not show on top of the gradient. here's my html now.

```
<div id="header">
        <ul id="headernav">  
                    <li><a class="gradient_black" href="#"><span id="home"></span></a></li>  
                    <li><a class="gradient_black" href="#"><img class="headericons" src="images/maps_30_white1.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Find Us" /></a></li>  
                    <li><a class="gradient_black" href="#"><img class="headericons" src="images/phone_white.png" height="30" width="30" alt="Click to Call" /></a></li>  
                    <li><a class="gradient_black" href="#"><img class="headericons" src="images/arrow_white.png" height="30" width="30" alt="More" /></a></li>  
            </ul>  
    </div>
```

and my edited css

```
#headernav a{
color: #fff;  
display: block;  /*displays the link as a block which stretches to the width specified-100% of its parent*/
width: 100%;/*width of link is 100% the width of its parent*/
text-align: center;  /*puts the text of the link in the centre of the display block*/
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
height: 60px;
}  



#home{
width:46px; 
margin: auto;
background: url('images/img_navsprites.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
display: block;
height: 60px;
}
```